# Google OneTap Signup prompt not displayed in IOS chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-signin, google-one-tap

We recenlty implemented the Google's OneTap signup feature in our web project.

It works fine in web and in android mobile browsers. But we were not getting the prompt in IOS Chrome.

As per the Google docs it should be covering IOS Chrome as well.
https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/supported-browsers

IOS chrome version we tried 87.0

Can someone help with this, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a way around this? I'm faced with same issue.